# Creating a one to many with an association table in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have an association  table called `SportTeams`:

```
public class SportTeam
{
        int SportId;
        int TeamId;
        Sport Sport;
        Team Team
}

public class Sport
{
    ICollection<SportTeam> SportTeams;
}

public class Team
{
    ICollection<SportTeam> SportTeams;
}
```

I mark this as an association table via fluent api

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SportTeam>().HasKey(q => new { q.SportId,q.TeamId }); // set the primary key of the table
modelBuilder.Entity<SportTeam>().HasRequired(s => s.Team).WithMany(t => t.SportTeams).HasForeignKey(s => s.TeamId);
modelBuilder.Entity<SportTeam>().HasRequired(s => s.Sport).WithMany(s => s.SportTeams).HasForeignKey(s => s.SportId);
```

Now I need to create a one to many with the association table `SportTeams`. Let's call that table `Matches`.

```
public class Matches
{
    int Id;
    int SportTeamId;
    SportTeam SportTeam;
}

public class SportTeam
{
    int SportId ;
    int TeamId;
    Sport Sport;
    Team Team;

    ICollection<Match> Matches;
}
```

I go back to the fluent api to make the changes for this one to many.

I say

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SportTeam>().HasMany(st => st.Matches).WithRequired(matches => matches.SportTeam).HasForeignKey(m => m.SportTeamId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

I get an error:

> The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

I believe this error states that my sportTeam PK is a composite key and in my HasForeignKey section I just specify one FK to connect with.

How should I go about this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're configuring the relashionship between `SportTeam` and `Matches` incorrectly.
So you say that `SportTeam` entity can have many `Matches` then it logic that `Matches` entity to have a foreign key that reference the `SportTeam` entity.

But if your look at your `SportTeam` entity configuration, you say it has a composite keys as primary key (`SportId`, `TeamId`).

You get this error:

> The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a
>   relationship constraint must be identical.

Because if you have composite key as primary key then the foreign key that refers to the primary key of `SportTeam` should also have both the properties implied in the composite key.

So to solve this, your `Matches` entity should look like this:

```
public class Matches
{
    public int Id  { get; set; }

    // these two properties below represent the foreign key that refers to SportTeam entity.
    public int SportId { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }

    public SportTeam SportTeam { get; set; };
}
```

In the `OnModelCreating` method you should have this line:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SportTeam>()
            .HasMany(st => st.Matches)
            .WithRequired(matches => matches.SportTeam)
            .HasForeignKey(m => new { m.SportId, m.TeamId }) // <-- the composite foreign keys.
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Instead of:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SportTeam>()
            .HasMany(st => st.Matches)
            .WithRequired(matches => matches.SportTeam)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.SportTeamId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

#### Side Note 1:

I always avoid using composite foreign key. If I end up with things like you have in your sample I just put a primary key property `Id` in `SportTeam` entity and make the couple of properties `SportId` and `TeamId` with unique constraint in database.

#### Side Note 2:

I don't know if you code like this in your real project but please use properties and make them public if necessary.

Comment: Thanks that worked. and no i dont code like that :) . It was just pseudo.